# homepage not rendered correctly for visitors coming from google/bing

Tags: wordpress

I have a weird problem on a website. Everything works OK when someone visits the site directly, but if a visitor enters the website from Google search or Bing the homepage looks very bad. I noticed this problem on Firefox, Chrome and Safari (latest versions).

First I though this was a Google cache problem and next time the crawler will visit the homepage it will also update the cached webpage.

But when I saw the same thing happening for visitors coming from Bing I started to think that this isn't search engine related and that it's something I've done wrong when I've coded the website.

This is how the homepage should look like: http://melisayavas.com/

And from Google or Bing: https://www.google.com/search?q=melisayavas

[image]

Does anyone know what or were the problem is?

Comment: I can't see what's looking bad. Please specify.

Comment: What's wrong actually? It looks just fine to me when i visit that site directly and from google serp. Please clarify what's the difference so i can try to help. Thanks

Comment: I see that the page layout is slightly different - I wouldn't call it bad, but different slightly. The HTML is exactly the same, so it has to be a CSS or Javascript issue.

I'll have to look at it from home when I have more time - there is a TON of javascript on that page.

Comment: not sure if this helps but when i use the google link the console gives this output http://t.co/wScOW6w

Comment: Yes, it's a wordpress plugin (slidedeck) that's adding all the JS and which isn't looking rendering the slides correctly for visitors coming from search engines. I'll add a screenshot to the main post.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the main post. That's how the homepage looks like for visitors coming from search engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site is broken in Google Chrome 18.  I suggest you fix it using this browser first, this might fix more issues related to search engine.

**EDIT**

I just saw your screenshot and it is exactly what I see in Chrome.

**EDIT 2**

I might be complete wrong, but when I click the link from the initial post http://melisayavas.com/ the site is broken. If reload the page it is also broken. If I go to the URL bar of the browser and hit 'enter' the site is fine.
I think the site is broken if the client sends a Referer header...

**EDIT 3**

I did a few tests with curl confirming my results. This test will results in the expected result:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.melisayavas.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182482/homepage-not-rendered-correctly-for-visitors-coming-from-google-bing/10182607#comment13069478_10182607');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

This on will result in a broken site:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.melisayavas.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182482/homepage-not-rendered-correctly-for-visitors-coming-from-google-bing/10182607#comment13069478_10182607');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
```

Having a referer in your request is what breaks the site. Do you have any part of your source code conditional to the referring url?

** EDIT 4 **

There is one piece of HTML code that is added when it's coming from a referring url:

```
<!-- Highlight Search Terms 0.7 ( RavanH - http://4visions.nl/en/wordpress-plugins/highlight-search-terms/ ) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var hlst_query = new Array("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182482/homepage-not-rendered-correctly-for-visitors-coming-from-google-bing/10182607#comment13069478_10182607");
var hlst_areas = new Array("div.hentry","#content","#main","div.content","#middle","#container","#wrapper","article");
</script>
```

I'm not familiar with Wordpress, be I believe this must come from a plugin called Highlight Search Terms, disabling it should fix your site.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that it's like this only if you come from Google or any other external referral. If you go directly to the website it will render correctly. 

And even if you're coming from an external referral, if you browse one-two pages and then come back to the homepage you will see that it's rendering just fine.

Comment: Wow that's weird. I browsed a few pages as you said and it works now. But I can't break it again... I'm trying to enter the site through google but it's fine now. Is there a sure way to break it again?

Comment: To break it I usually do this: enter google search for melisayavas and I enter the site. It breaks every time when I do this.

Comment: Not everytime for me. When I click the link http://melisayavas.com/ you included in your post it breaks.

Comment: I was able to confirm my second edit this morning, I'll add proper results in EDIT 3

Comment: I don't have a referrer request from what I know. I've added the whole <head> section in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/1brtsfcQ

Comment: Great! I disabled the plugin it apparently it's working fine now. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few code errors, like a duplicate nav div and a missing closing div, etc. Fix those and see how it displays.

[[Invalid] Markup Validation of  melisayavas.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//melisayavas.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.